# どの言葉がなくなったのですか Which words are missing?

Tags: word-choice, particle-に, ellipsis

次の文は雑誌の広告写真についていたキャプションです。

> 「やさしいかわ　ひとに　ちきゅうに」

日本エコレザーの広告です。写真では、三人の子供が地球を持っています。やさしい革とは、アレルギーの原因となる金属とか有害物質のない皮革です。

それを考えると、どういう意味がありますか。

> 「やさしいかわ。人に作られた。地球のために」
>
> 「やさしいかわ。人のために。地球のために」

など。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

例の文章は省略された言い回しのようなものですけれども、強調されている言葉は「やさしい」です。そして、「やさしい」について考えますと、「誰にとってやさしいのか、何にとってやさしいのか」という疑問が自然に頭の中に浮かんできます。この観点から見ますと、「人に​**[作]{●}[ら]{●}[れ]{●}[た]{●}**​」のではなく、「何々​**[の]{●}[た]{●}[め]{●}[に]{●}**​」でもなく、「何々に​**[と]{●}[っ]{●}[て]{●}**（やさしい）​」や「何々に​**[対]{●}[し]{●}[て]{●}**​（やさしい）」というほうが正しい解釈でしょう。

Comment: 明快な説明をしてくれて、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

たいていの人は、ぱっと見てこれは[倒置]{とうち}（inversion, anastrophe）だと認識すると思います。

> 「やさしいかわ　ひとに　ちきゅうに」 （倒置が起こっている）
>    ←　「ひとに、ちきゅうに、やさしいかわ」（もとの語順）

「人にも地球にも優しい革」、「人間にも環境にも優しい革」という意味です。

「～に優しい」は、"to be kind to (someone)" という意味です。

ですから、「どの言葉がなくなったのですか」への答えとしては、語順が変わっただけで、どの言葉もなくなっていない、ということになると思います。

Comment: なるほどね。ご回答ありがとうございました！